# N-API Continuous callbacks for c++ media stream

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm trying to create a node interface for a c++ media player. Upon decoding of a frame, there is an event which allows me to access the frame data, which I'm trying to funnel into node. But I can't seem to figure out how to get that kind of functionality to work with the functions available in [the node api](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html). My approach, for the time being, is to figure out a push mechanism to get the data from c++ to javascript where all i need is to initialize a callback in javascript, since it seems more elegant. If that fails I could create a polling loop in js to check if there is new frame data, but it seems less efficient.

I've tried with [napi_create_async_work](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_create_async_work), by creating a lambda function in the execute parameter function, which would allow me to call [napi_make_callback](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_make_callback) for every frame callback, but then I get the following error :

```
Fatal error in HandleScope::HandleScope
Entering the V8 API without proper locking in place
```

I'm likely approaching this incorrectly, its the first time I use n-api.

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: The documentation leaves a lot to be desired and examples are hard to come by. I'm in the same boat.

Comment: I believe the problem is simply that async functions can't call into the memory stack which node-api uses, but there seems to be a fix coming into a node release very soon : https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/17887

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs If you're still looking for a current solution, I've update my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is mainly pertaining to the fact you can’t access V8 (JavaScript) memory outside the event-loop’s main thread. If you're creating an async thread, by default you're also creating a new memory stack.

Fortunately, a fix is on the way which should allow thread safe access with
[napi_create_threadsafe_function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/17887) (example [here](https://github.com/gabrielschulhof/abi-stable-node-addon-examples/blob/tsfn_example/thread_safe_function/node-api/tsfn_example.c))

**Until then** 
There is a [header only C++ package](https://github.com/mika-fischer/napi-thread-safe-callback) which integrates great with the [C++ N-API wrapper](https://nodejs.github.io/node-addon-api/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Napi-addon-api is update. These is a good way that use the Napi::ThreadSafeFunction.
[Doc and example.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/threadsafe_function.md)